# LINQ .contains not pulling correct results from database

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to pull some records from a database using EF and LINQ.
However, on some specific cases with some specific strings (which do not seem to have anything special to them), some db records are being completely ignored.

I've created a new database (with the exact same schema), and inserted the exact same record. Using this new database, I was able to retrieve the record, using the exact same LINQ command. 
It just happens with certain strings in what seems to be a completely random way.

```
public async Task<List<Customer>> Search(string nameOrTIN)
{
    var wordsInName = nameOrTIN.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    IQueryable<Customer> query = this.context.Customers.AsQueryable();
    foreach (var word in wordsInName)
    {
        query = query.Where(o => o.Name.ToLower().Contains(word.ToLower()) || 
               o.TIN.ToLower().Contains(word.ToLower())).Take(10).OrderBy(p => p.Name);
    }
    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Calling Search function with "John Oliver" as a parameter should return all the records that have the strings "John" and "Oliver" in them, but none are returned even though there is a "John Oliver" record in the database.

*Edit*
Just found out that if I look for "Oliver John" instead of "John Oliver" all the correct records are returned.  Just to add a little bit to the weirdness.

*Edit*
Edited to show a part of the query I omitted when posting the question which I thought would not be necessary to show. However, that was what was actually causing my problem.
The .Take(10) within my loop was what was the culprit of my suffering.
I was able to figure it our thanks to Ivan Stoev's comment.
Sorry y'all!

Comment: There is nothing *much* wrong with your query i can see, However.... Have you checked you can query anything from this table? i mean if you comment out the for loop, do you get any results?

Comment: If you have two identical database and perform the same query you should get the same results.  Therefore the two databases are not identical.  We cannot solve the issue without have the words that do not work.

Comment: @TheGeneral Yes, that query has been in production for some time now.  It works perfectly around 97% of the time and it pulls all the records correctly. It's just that 3% of the time that is bothering our customers.

Comment: @jdweng Schema wise they were created with the exact same query.  Only the data inside them is different.  Both contain a "John Oliver" record though.  It's pretty weird! :O

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve]. It is key that the word `John Oliver` is **in the code** you share with us. Also, please make sure you have run the [mcve] and it exhibits the bug.

Comment: Have you proved sufficiently this isn't a Unicode thing, ie the text is exactly how you expect? No diatrics ect, or weird characters.

Comment: @TheGeneral Yes.  I just edited my question to state that just by inverting my search query, the correct result is found just fine.

Comment: Try moving the `OrderBy` outside the `foreach` loop. By definition multiple `OrderBy` should be ignored and only last applied, but one never knows (especially with EF Core).

Answer (score 0):

You are inadvertently updating the Customers object and not resetting it properly between searches. So you're starting with a queryable that has already had other filters applied to it.

Try changing it to this:

`IQueryable<Customer> query = this.context.Customers.AsQueryable();`

Comment: Let me give it a go.

Comment: It is **incredibly** rare that adding `AsQueryable` is useful.

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work.  And to add to the weirdness, I noticed that if I type for "Oliver John" instead of "John Oliver" the correct result is returned.

Comment: @JaimeCalderón We need a [mcve]. I don't think the bug is in the code you are showing us.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a logger to your database context and printing it to your console or log file.

When I run a similar query on my database EF uses CHARINDEX, I think maybe this CHARINDEX is throwing off your query somehow when you loop. I think you can rewrite this loop/query to be much better and easier to read btw

```
WHERE ((CHARINDEX(@__ToLower_0, LOWER([o].[Name])) > 0) OR (@__ToLower_0 = N'')) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__ToLower_0, LOWER([o].[TIN])) > 0) OR (@__ToLower_0 = N''))
      ORDER BY [o].[Name]
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  It didn't fix my issue, though :(

Comment: It looks like the query is building like it should, so i'm not sure what you're issue is, I'm sorry